# Combinatorics of the Zeta function of a variety

Tags: power-series, diophantine-equations, generating-functions, exponential-function, combinatorics

I want to know if there is a good combinatorial interpretation of what the Zeta function of a variety $X$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ counts. It is defined as $$\exp\sum N_j/j\,t^j,$$ where $N_j$ is the number of points in $X$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^j}$.

I hope an answer will be something along the following lines: the coefficients of $\sum N_j/j\,t^j$ count the orbits of the solution sets under iterations of the Fröbenius automorphism, and the exponential of the sequence somehow counts representatives.

I reckon this is very elementary combinatorics. A concise source I could use to produce such a combinatorial statement would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeta function counts **effective divisors**, e.g. objects of the form $\sum n_i p_i$ where

- $p_i$ is a point of $X$ over a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$,
- $n_i \ge 0$ are non-negative integers, and
- the expression $\sum n_i p_i$ is Galois-invariant.

If $X$ is affine, this is equivalent to saying that it counts ideals of the coordinate ring of $X$; in fact in this setting the zeta function is more or less the Dedekind zeta function of the coordinate ring.

This is a corollary of a version of the [exponential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) which asserts that

$$\exp \sum \frac{z_j}{j} t^j = \sum_{n \ge 0} Z_{S_n}(z_1, z_2, ...) t^n$$

where $Z_{S_n}$ are the [cycle index polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) of the symmetric groups. See [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/gila-vi-the-cycle-index-polynomials-of-the-symmetric-groups/) and [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/newtons-sums-necklace-congruences-and-zeta-functions-ii/) for details.

Comment: These are not divisors though, they seem to be 0-cycles.

Comment: I don't know what the standard definition of a divisor on a variety over a non-algebraically closed field is, but if this isn't it then substitute whatever the correct word is.

Comment: Qiaochu: I think what hilbert points out is that a closed point is of codimension $>1$.

Comment: 'May be' of course, not 'is' :-)